# i want to get values in mysql using full calendar plugin

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Where can I put a for loop in my PHP code so that it will loop if we have a date on database?
here is the code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        defaultDate: "<?php echo '2015-05-12'; ?>",
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
        <?php 
            $kweri = $connection->query("select * from caltbl") or die(mysqli_error());
            while($event = $kweri->fetch_assoc())
            {
        ?>
            {
                title: '<?php echo $event->calName?>',
                start: '<?php echo $event->calDate?>'
            },
        <?php }?>


        ]
    });

});
```

title: 'All Day Event' = Title of the event
start: '2015-05-13' = Date 
SO if i duplicate it 10 times in my calendar it shows it 10 times also

No problem with my java script what so ever all i need is the PHP and how to set it up

Comment: What do you mean by loop if we have a date on database? A shot in the dark: are you hoping you find the first date with an event, and then set the default date to that? Or are you wanting to write event objects, each with a title and start date, to the output?

Comment: for example you have a event table and you have a title and event field so if we have a record may 08, 2015 and title is sample it will show it on the calendar. calendar means my full calendar not the calendar on my PC hehehe

Comment: Do you already have all of the events in some variable, such as $events? Have you already established a database connection?

Comment: Yeah. ill post my current code on my question ok so that you can see it.

Comment: don't mix php and javascript... just asking for confusion and more debugging efforts than necessary. The documents show how you can pass a url and let plugin manage getting the events

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: "<?php echo '2015-05-12'; ?>",
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
<?php foreach ($events as $event) { ?>
            {
                title: '<?php echo $event->title; ?>',
                start: '<?php echo $event->date->toDateTimeString(); ?>'
            },
<?php } ?>
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: yeah.. that was correct. maybe i should try it. ill get back to you

Comment: How didn't it work? :) What happened, and what did you expect?

Comment: Yep, but what errors are you seeing, if any? What unexpected behaviour, if any? Have you added var_dump(x) points in there to make sure you're getting the data you're expecting? Develop your debug skills! :) Also, out of curiosity; what language do you speak ("kweri", "caltbl")?

Comment: Oh, looking at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php , it seems that you'll need to do something like "$event['calName']" instead of "$event->calName". Try that?

Comment: Great, glad I could help! I'd encourage you to edit your first post with the solution, or accept an answer?

Comment: i just found out the get-events.php in the calendar plugin then I query the data and fetch it using json :) thanks anyway